# Get updated value of an HTTP Observable

Tags: angular

Say I have a code that gets the users from the API:

```
getUsers() {
   this.users$ = this.userService.getUsers();
}
```

And I display the users in my view using the `async` pipe.

At some point on my code, I'd like to call `getUsers()` again to fetch an updated list of users, but the view doesn't get updated with a new list because presumably its the `async` pipe that handles the observable and it doesn't know to call the service again.

How can I work around this issue? Do I need to use `.subscribe()` instead?

Comment: calling `getUsers()` again does not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because this.users$ observable is already completed (promise resolved by async) Simply return getUsers observable from this method and use subscribe method to fetch them

```
getUsers(): Observable<User[]> {
   return this.userService.getUsers();
}
```

Note: subscribe method doesn't mean it will listen to changes of observable, it will listen to them only if observable not completed, but as long as HttpClient completes it, you don't need to worry about memory leak

To comply it with your implementation it will be something like:

```
this.someService.doSomething().pipe(
  switchMap(something => this.userService.getUsers())
).subscribe(users => {})
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working. I'm calling it inside a Promise like this: `this.someService.doSomething().toPromise().then(() => { this.users$ = this.getUsers(); })`;

Comment: Provide as much code as you have, Its not possible to resolve problem without knowing entire picture. I've changed my answer slightly. In short, in Angular you almost never use promises, because its 1000 times easier to operate with observables

Comment: Thanks, followed your advise and used switchMap instead. Got it working now.